# cannot execute binary file (OSX & Raspbian)

Tags: linux, macos, raspberry-pi

I tried to execute a file it keeps giving me `cannot execute binary file`error

```
myfile Permission: 777
```

Running file myfile

```
myfile: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

How can I run this file on mac or raspbian or what library am I missing?

Comment: You cannot run the same file on a OS X ( Intel x86-x64 ) and Raspbian ( ARM ) system.  More information is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

The file is compiled for a Linux environment, as is made clear by the sentence `for GNU/LINUX 2.6.18`, and the reason is that it uses shared libraries. This rules out a Mac, because, even though there are certainly MAC models running on Intel 80386 chips, none uses the Linux shared libraries.

On the other hand, though you may have a Linux distro installed on the Raspberry Pi (Debian or Arch, or ...) the `cpu architecture` for which this file has been compiled is `Intel 80386`, which differs greatly from the `ARM` architecture appropriate to the Raspberry Pi cpu.

You will have to search for versions of this program which have been ported to different environments. The Pi's repos provide exactly this kind of functionality, i.e., a collection of programs typical of Linux, but recompiled to run on an ARM architecture. With Mac, the operating systems being different, you may end up searching for a different program, performing the same tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll have to put this on our other server as it is only compiled for GNU/Linux

Comment: @DouglasDC3 Let's just hope it has been compiled to work with a version of the shared libraries which is compatible with the one you have on your other system...